# Photon will deform through time?

Tags: photons, universe

Is it possible that photon will deform through time? so after millions of years a single photon will get redshifted? Can we test this possibility by current technology?

If this is true, what scientist now think that the universe is accelerated (even long distance galaxy move faster than speed of light) is actually the deformation of photon through time.

Comment: That's a very natural thought to have -- you're not the first to think of that! What you are proposing is called a "tired light" theory. Look it up; many such theories have been tried, but none of them are compatible with all current experiment results.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light

Comment: @knzhou and anna thank you, I have already read the wikipedia page. There is no direct experiment to test this, and this experiment seems almost impossible.